# Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.setApplicationContext()]

Tags: spring, testng, cglib

I have a spring data test class (using TestNG) to test my spring data repository. I just encountered this warning/ info messages after the test was started and wondered if this needs to be fixed?

> 2018-08-06 15:30:07.932  WARN 8028 --- [           main]
>   o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Unable to proxy
>   interface-implementing method [public final void
>   org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)]
>   because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK
>   proxies instead!
>
> 2018-08-06 15:30:07.934  INFO 8028 --- [           main]
>   o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final
>   void
>   org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)]
>   cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed
>   to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized
>   fields in the proxy instance.

For Code completeness here is my test base class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RepositoryConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true", "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true"})
public class AbstractRespositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

}
```

Why does Spring want to create a proxy around AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests?
How can (or should) I resolve this warning?